# Count number of hidden elements by overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, css

I have a full width div with a repeating element. On overflow, I hide the overflown content and don't display whitepace. My problem is I want to count the number of hidden items (or displayed items I guess) but cannot figure out how to.

You can see a basic example of this at https://codepen.io/joshuaohana/pen/aqPJMr

In this case the css governing the hiding is

```
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you remove the overflow line you get a scroll bar, put it back in, no scroll bar.

What I need is a way to count the items that are hidden in the lost overflow section, when overflow is set to hidden.

The only things I've found are trying to count which elements have hidden, but that doesn't apply to overflow items. I can't find any differing qualifiers that I can search against.

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: @sol Yes jQuery is fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an approach with jQuery. Detect the width of the containing `div`. Then use the `offset()` method to count the number of elements who have a `left` coordinate outside of this width.

```js
var parentContainerWidth = $("div").width();
var elementCount = $('span').filter(function() {
  return $(this).offset().left >= parentContainerWidth;
}).length;
alert(elementCount);
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {
  background: pink;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>here is an item 1</span>
  <span>here is an item 2</span>
  <span>here is an item 3</span>
  <span>here is an item 4</span>
  <span>here is an item 5</span>
  <span>here is an item 6</span>
  <span>here is an item 7</span>
  <span>here is an item 8</span>
  <span>here is an item 9</span>
  <span>here is an item 10</span>
  <span>here is an item 11</span>
  <span>here is an item 12</span>
  <span>here is an item 13</span>
  <span>here is an item 14</span>
  <span>here is an item 15</span>
  <span>here is an item 16</span>
  <span>here is an item 17</span>
  <span>here is an item 18</span>
  <span>here is an item 19</span>
  <span>here is an item 20</span>
  <span>here is an item 21</span>
  <span>here is an item 22</span>
  <span>here is an item 23</span>
  <span>here is an item 24</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have a div with multiple <p> tags as children.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have a div with multiple <p> tags as children. `div { line-height: 1.5; max-height: calc(var(--line-height) * 3); overflow: hidden;}` and the child p tags have css like - p { display: inline-block; }. So any children p tags which can't set in the max-width will be overflown. Now, in this scenario how can I count the number hidden or visible elements. var(--line-height) is the variable I have defines which is equal to 1.8.